# How does SRCNN network retain the original size of image? Why does the image not become smaller with every convolution?

Tags: deep-learning

[SRCNN](https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.00092) is one of the most well-known recent techniques in Image super-resolution. The authors propose a CNN layered structure, where they use 4 convolutional layers one after the other with filter sizes of 9, 1, 5, 3.

According to my understanding, this would mean that the image size would progressively decrease (except in the second layer). Even if padding is used to keep the image size same, the first operation would mean the addition of 4 zeros along every edge. So, the filter of size 5 would basically see only zeros at one end, which should lead to terrible resolution along edges.

The paper does not explain how they got around the problem of decreasing image size. Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This github repository shows the approach(or insight) to work with the edge problem. You may need to modify it a bit to fit into your code.

https://github.com/jormeli/srcnn-keras

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply,

I have been working in this domain and i finally understood why the image size isn't decreasing even when applying convolution operations. Let us take the Architecture mentioned by the author i.e. ( 9 - 3 - 5 ).

In the code implementation, the image is divided into 32x32 sub images and for each sub image its hr and lr version is prepared by downscaling and upscaling. So we prepare a hr patch of size [20:20] and lr patch [32:32]. (Before giving these patches as input to first conv layer, we remove the 6 bordering pixels so the hr patch shape would be 32 - (6+6) = 20 x 20 thats why i have mentioned hr patch above as [20:20])

the whole trick is in padding, we provide the LR patch as input to the CNN

**First conv layer** : filter size  = 9, padding = Valid, so the shape of
output = n-f+1 ( 32 - 9 + 1 ) = 24, So output of first layer is 24x24 image

**Second conv layer** : filter size  = 3, padding = Same, so the shape of
output = Shape of input, So output of second layer is 24x24 image

**Third conv layer** : filter size  = 5, padding = Valid, so the shape of
output = n-f+1 ( 24 - 5 + 1 ) = 20, So output of third layer is 20x20 image.

So finally we have a LR patch of 20x20 and HR patch of 20x20, we compare this, perform mse and backpropagate errors.

So here we donot actually increase the size of image, we keep the size of image same and we make adjustments so that the image appears better.

Cheers :)